# Tag proposal: topics about very similar functions

Tags: discussion, tagging

I feel that for every new user (but not limited to them, very often I feel the same) the flood of functions is a cursed blessing.

"*It's great I can extract part of the matrix in 20 different ways, but which should I use and when? What are the possible issues raised by each?*" -- this is something that comes into my mind many times.

Documentation doesn't help so much, I feel that "coding style" should be discussed there more widely; instead it is mostly a collection of "raw" examples. Some are very neat, true, but confusion is still present.

---

I would like to have a separate tag to mark/find topics about comparison of functions.

Here are a few examples of the kind of topics I have in mind:

- [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/5478)
- [Union vs DeleteDuplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64040/5478)
- [What is the point of Refresh if Dynamic has an UpdateInterval option?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14368/5478)
- [Are there advantages to using generalized Part extraction instead of specialized functions like First, Last?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4030/5478)
- [Defer, Hold, Unevaluated, Inactivate — which one when?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98874/5478)
- [What are the known differences between Save and DumpSave, and how to account for them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19361/5478)
- [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/5478)

My candidate is [comparison](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) meant to be used with [functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions)/[coding-style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-style)/[functional-style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-style). I'm not sure if this is best.

Or maybe we don't need anything new; if so, let's establish a standard appraoch.

Comment: I don't much like [tag:comparison]. To my mind it suggests questions about relational operators. I would suggest [tag:best-practice] if we're going to go down this road.

Comment: I can see that such a tag could help those who are searching the site. However, we already have many questions on the site where the answers discuss best practice. Is somebody going to go through all the old questions and add the new tag to those that need it? If that isn't done, the new tag won't help search much.

Comment: How would we enforce the coupling of [tag:comparison] with the other tags you want it coupled with? I can't see a way to do that, and without that coupling, [tag:comparison]  seems ambiguous.

Comment: @m_goldberg I will, there are not so many topics I'd mark anyway. The question is, is this helpful? If so, the more are marked the better, so what we miss some old topics. About coupling, the same way [tag:filtering] [tag:gathering] etc work. I don't know if best practice is the best, I feel that it is to narrow. p.s. thanks for the edit.

Comment: How would that tag relate to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same as the [tag:guidelines] tag?

Comment: @Karsten7. wonuldn't at all. It should only be applied to topics like linked above. "I know I can use Part and Extract and Take, what's the point of those 3 functions then?"

Comment: Perhaps I would be more enthusiastic about this proposal if you were to edit your question and add the tag wiki you would provide for it. A good tag wiki would help to convince me (and perhaps others) that we need this.

Comment: @Karsten7. haven't seen that one! guidelines + functions seems perfect.

Comment: + a better tag wiki for [tag:guidelines].

Comment: @m_goldberg Karsten will try to edit guidelines wiki in a free time, thanks for discussion.

Comment: Related: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174/18476

Comment: @Karsten7. Please consider posting an answer that editing guidelines is the way to go. Let's see if others agree.

Comment: Do you still prefer creating a new tag [tag:comparison]? If not, like your [comment](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/tag-proposal-topics-about-very-similar-functions#comment7136_1739) indicated, it'd make more sense if you'd write an answer that also includes the new wiki text and maybe a comment on how that fits into [this discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174/18476).

Comment: @Karsten7. wikin not yet thought through but I have post answers

Comment: Another one: [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)

Comment: @shrx good one, thx!

Comment: Another: [Good clearing practices](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/good-clearing-practices) What's the current status of this issue, has it been decided how to address it?

Comment: @shrx while issue gathered attention, I can't say so about solutions proposals :/

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that [guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guidelines) + [functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) has a little bit broader meaning and I would like to have a solution that tags the group of topics more precisely.

The problem is with functions guidelines about single function, e.g. `Condition` here:

[Placement of Condition /; expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/533/placement-of-condition-expressions)

I'd prefer to have a clear way to sift that cases.

That's why I'm after [comparison](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) or any synonim, with apriopriate wiki (tbd).

Comment: I think [tag:comparison] is too broad and could lead to mis-tagged questions (as @m_goldberg pointed out). The improved tag name would be [tag:function-comparison].

Comment: @shrx I;m fine with that :)

Answer (score 1):

We should go with [guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guidelines) + [functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) with updated wiki (tbd).

Combining tags works quite well for [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation)+[filtering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filtering) and friends, so this is not a problem.